# google rejected my ionic application for asking for the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

google rejected my ionic application for asking for the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission, but in my android manifest this option is not enabled.
follows the androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name="io.ionic.starter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>

<!-- Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Camera, Photos, input file -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Geolocation API -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />





<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<!-- Network API -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Navigator.getUserMedia -->
<!-- Video -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- Audio -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<!-- button vibrate-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

So I didn't find the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission in my androidManifest and I went after debugging better and in the manifest-merger-release-report apk log file I found

ADDED from [:capacitor-android] C:\Users\test\Desktop\test\test\node_modules@capacitor\android\capacitor\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:44:25-79
uses-permission#android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

So the capacitor is adding the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission? Has anyone had something like this before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Ah that thing will make you mad xD I had it with 2 apps, will dig out what I did and post back. As far as I remember, it was small change(s) in Android manifest and some juggling with already uploaded app versions on Google Console.